# Case Classes w/ Option Parameters & Case Matching

Tags: scala

I have a case class that has multiple parameters of which some are Options. Here is a simplified example:

```
case class Foobar(a: String, b: Option[String], c: Option[CustomClass])
```

I want to be able to match cases of Foobar where b and/or c is not None. For example, one case could be:

```
testResult match {
    case Foobar("str1", Some(_), None) => "good"
    case Foobar("str2", None, Some(_)) => "ok"
    case _ => "bad"
}
```

Furthermore, I want to reference the case patterns via variables and this is where I'm stuck. I want to do something like the following:

```
val goodPat = Foobar("str1", Some(_), None) // compile fail
val okPat = Foobar("str2", None, Some(_)) // compile fail
testResult match {
    case `goodPat` => "good"
    case `okPat` => "ok"
    case _ => "bad"
}
```

Is something like this possible? Is there another way to specify "not None"? Is there another way to approach this problem?

EDIT: I'm adding more details and context to the question. I have a large List of 2-tuples representing unit tests for a particular function. The 2-tuples represent the input and expected output. Eg.

```
// imagine this list is much bigger and Foobar contains more Option parameters
val tests = List(
    ("test1", Foobar("idkfa", None, None)),
    // I know these fail to compile but I need to do something like this
    ("test2", Foobar("idclip", Some("baz"), Some(_)),
    ("test3", Foobar("iddqd", Some(_), None)
)

tests.foreach(test => {
    val (input, expected) = test
    myFunction(input) match {
        case `expected` => println("ok")
        case _ => println("bad")
    }
})
```

Comment: Why would you want to match variable name in case class? I do not think it's necessary. What is the problem with your first approach?

Comment: I'm not matching variable names. I'm trying to move the pattern definitions outside the match block because the actual code is much more complicated and I need to programatically assign the patterns.

Comment: `val a = Foo(x)` is the syntax for intantiaing a class. You can not use a wild card pattern matcher like `_` here.

Comment: Ok so you have a long list of tuples of test names and expected outcomes. Are you saying that for certain tests you don't care what the string value of b parameter is? While for many others you care what exactly is the string value of b parameter?

Comment: @Samar yes, that is correct: sometimes the exact b parameter doesn't matter, I just need to know that it is not None

Comment: @beetea You `can not` create an instance of class `Foobar` as `Foobar("iddqd", Some(_))`. A list contains instances. And instances are instantiated by invoking the constructor with other instance values as parameters. And `Some(_)` is not an instance value.

Comment: @beetea Check my answer and ask if you don't understand something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you seeking for something like this:

```
case class DoomOpt(s: String)
case class Foobar(a: String, b: Option[String], c: Option[DoomOpt])

def myFunction(s: String): Foobar = { // your code here }

val tests = Map[String, PartialFunction[Foobar, Unit]](
    "idkfa" → { case Foobar("idkfa", None, None) ⇒ },
    "test2" → { case Foobar("idclip", Some("baz"), Some(_)) ⇒ },
    "test3" → { case Foobar("iddqd", Some(_), None) ⇒ },
    "idspispopd" → { case Foobar("idspispopd", Some(_), None) ⇒ }
  )

tests.foreach { case (input, checker) =>
  if (checker.isDefinedAt(myFunction(input)))
    println("ok")
  else
    println("bad")
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I need but I'm trying to understand how this works. Specifically, `myFunction` is defined to be an instance of `Foobar(s, None, None)` so doesn't this mean `checker.isDefinedAt(myFunction(input))` will only be true when the last two Options are None? EDIT: Oh, that was just an example. I think I get it now.

Comment: In this case yes. But your function returns dynamic result of the Foobar class which depends on "input". It could be any instance of the Foobar class.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thanks. I'm still learning Scala and not having a "return" statement in functions still throws me off from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching uses extractors which provide the unapply function to deconstruct the object. So... you can just supply your custom extractor in this case. Create a list of these extractor test cases and apply them one by one.

```
case class Foobar(s: String, o: Option[Int])

trait TestExtractor {
  def unapply(fbar: Foobar): Boolean
}

object somePatExtractor extends TestExtractor {
  def unapply(fbar: Foobar): Boolean = fbar match {
    case Foobar("yes", Some(_)) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

object nonePatExtractor extends TestExtractor {
  def unapply(fbar: Foobar): Boolean = fbar match {
    case Foobar("yes", None) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

object bazPatExtractor extends TestExtractor {
  def unapply(fbar: Foobar): Boolean = fbar match {
    case Foobar("yes", Some("baz")) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}


val testList: List[(String, TestExtractor)] = List(("test1", nonePatExtractor), ("test2", bazPatExtractor), ("test3", somePatExtractor))

val fooToTest = Foobar("yes", Some(5))

testList.foreach({
  case (testName, extractor) => {
    fooToTest match {
      case pat @ extractor() => println("testName :: " + testName + ", Result :: ok")
      case _ => println("testName :: " + testName + ", Result :: bad")
    }
  }
})
```

And if you are looking for a more extendible approach then you can consider something like following,

```
case class Foobar(s: String, o1: Option[Int], o2: Option[String])

case class TestCondition(df: Foobar => Boolean) {
  def test(foobar: Foobar): Boolean = df(foobar)
}

val o1IsNone = TestCondition(f => f.o1.isEmpty)
val o1IsSome = TestCondition(f => f.o1.isDefined)

val o2IsNone = TestCondition(f => f.o2.isEmpty)
val o2IsSome = TestCondition(f => f.o2.isDefined)

case class TestCase(tcs: List[TestCondition]) {
  def test(foobar: Foobar) = tcs.foldLeft(true)({ case (acc, tc) => acc && tc.test(foobar) })
}

val testList = List[(String, TestCase)](
  ("test1", TestCase(List(o1IsSome, o2IsSome))),
  ("test2", TestCase(List(o1IsSome, o2IsNone))),
  ("test3", TestCase(List(o1IsNone, o2IsSome))),
  ("test4", TestCase(List(o1IsNone, o2IsNone)))
)

val foobarToTest = Foobar("yes", Some(5), None)

testList.foreach({
  case (testName, testCase) => {
    foobarToTest match {
      case foobar: Foobar if testCase.test(foobar) => println("testName :: " + testName + ", Result :: ok")
      case _ => println("testName :: " + testName + ", Result :: bad")
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this would get complicated for case classes with many parameters, with multiple Options (ie. I'd need to create ton of TestExtractor objects). This does give me another idea, however. I think I should just wrap the patterns in a validation function.